# How can I get IHtmlDocument2 in chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, ihtmldocument2

In Internet Explorer, I can use IHtmlDocument2 to get the html document.

```
function GetCurrentBrowserDOM: WideString;
var
  hr: HRESULT;
  CurrentIE: IWebbrowser2;
  Wnd: HWND;
  WndChild:HWND;
  document: IDispatch;
  RootNode: IHTMLDocument2;
  innerHtml: WideString;
begin
  Result := '';
  Wnd := GetForegroundWindow;
  WndChild := FindWindowEx(Wnd, 0,'Frame Tab', nil);
  WndChild := FindWindowEx(WndChild, 0,'TabWindowClass', nil);
  WndChild := FindWindowEX(WndChild, 0, 'Shell DocObject View', nil);
  WndChild := FindWindowEX(WndChild, 0, 'Internet Explorer_Server', nil);//find Internet
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    hr := GetIEFromHWND(WndChild, CurrentIE);
    if hr = S_OK then
    begin
      document := CurrentIE.Document;
      document.QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2, RootNode);
      innerHtml := RootNode.body.innerHTML;
    end;
  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;

function GetIEFromHWND(WHandle: HWND; var IE: IWebbrowser2): HRESULT;
type
  TObjectFromLResult = function(LRESULT: LRESULT; const IID: TGUID; wParam: WPARAM; out PObject): HRESULT; stdcall;
var
  hInst: HWND;
  lRes: Cardinal;
  MSG: Integer;
  pDoc: IHTMLDocument2;
  ObjectFromLresult: TObjectFromLresult;
begin

  hInst := LoadLibrary('Oleacc.dll');
  @ObjectFromLresult := GetProcAddress(hInst, 'ObjectFromLresult');
  if @ObjectFromLresult <> nil then begin
    try
      MSG := RegisterWindowMessage('WM_HTML_GETOBJECT');
      SendMessageTimeOut(WHandle, MSG, 0, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, lRes);
      Result := ObjectFromLresult(lRes, IHTMLDocument2, 0, pDoc);
      Result := GetLastError;
      if Result = S_OK then
        (pDoc.parentWindow as IServiceprovider).QueryService(IWebbrowserApp, IWebbrowser2, IE);
    finally
      FreeLibrary(hInst);
    end;
end;
```

I used spy++ to look for the chrome frame handle, and I found them.

```
  Wnd := GetForegroundWindow;
  WndChild := FindWindowEx(Wnd, 0, 'Chrome_WidgetWin_0', nil);
  WndChild := FindWindowEx(WndChild, 0, 'Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND', nil);
  WndChild := FindWindowEx(WndChild, 0, 'CompositorHostWindowClass', nil);
```

But it can't catch the result in function called ObjectFromLresult.

```
ObjectFromLresult(lRes, IHTMLDocument2, 0, pDoc);
```

The error code I got was 127.

Does it mean chrome browser not support this way to fetch its html document?

If the answer is yes, is there another way to catch it?

thanks a lot.

PS: I have tried to use MSAA tree, but it didn't work too.(Can only fetch the title)

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, IHtmlDocument2 is interface supported only in IE hosting objects, WebKit engine used in Chrome doesn't support it. You can however use MSAA to access elements, but you need to enable accessibility feature first: http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/accessibility

Or alternatively you can access DOM via remote debugging protocol: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/protocol/1.0/index